# How to Add ACF Date & Time field to Woocommerce Emails line items

Tags: email, woocommerce

I have a Date & Time as an ACF field for my products which are events, I need to add the date into the emails that get sent out. Below is as far as I've got, it will display the word Date, but the ACF field doesn't display. I'm sure it's something really obvious but I can't see it :(.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
// Add ACF Date & Time to New Order Email
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'email_confirmation_display_order_items', 10, 4);

function email_confirmation_display_order_items($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text) {

echo '<div>Date: '. wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'event_date_and_time') .'</div>';
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in the end...

```
// Add ACF Info to New Order Email
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'email_confirmation_display_order_items', 10, 4);

function email_confirmation_display_order_items($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text) {

    $product = $item->get_product();

    if ( empty( $product ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $date = get_field( 'event_date_and_time', $product->get_id() );

    if ( !empty( $date ) ) {
        echo '<div style="font-size:10px;">Date: '. $date .'</div>';
    }
}
```